# Access Android in-app purchase info with asp.net c#

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I currently have an app on the Android Google Play market which has a few in app purchases available.
I am looking to add another one which would be a subscription to give them extra functionality not only in the Android app, but also on my website too.
The availability of the feature on the website would be tied into the Android app and if the stop subscribing in the app then I would want to stop access on the website too.

Is there a way to check if they have purchased an in app upgrade using asp.net (preferably with c#, however open to other methods) and if so could you point me in the right direction as to what I need to do please?

My attempts at Googling this has returned no results so I am not sure if this is possible or if my Googling is just rubbish!

Thanks.

Comment: I'm no mobile app developer. But I assume the app itself has a way of telling what's been purchased? And I assume your app has a way of communicating to your servers, perhaps via WCF? Why not have the app transmit a message to the server saying what's been purchased, then update your centralized database.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yeah, that was going to be my route if there was no way of checking via the website. The issue with that is, if the user cancels the subscription outside of the app (in the Play store) and uninstalls before it gets the chance update the database they would be able to continue using the website even though they have cancelled. I guess the way round that would be to force the user to use the app every so often say at least once a week to allow the app itself to update the database. But really I would rather avoid forcing the user to do anything like that if I can.

Comment: In that case, did you look at the [Purchase Status API](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/gp-purchase-status-api.html)?